Is there some sort of multilevel KNN/ML model I can use to figure out which users will buy specific products?
I am wondering if there is some sort of multilevel model that I can use to identify likely buyers of specific products or create a lookalike audience.
The issue is that I have 1000s of products and around a million users. It would be computationally infeasible to create a model for every product.
The structure I am thinking of is the first level is a product and the next level is all the users in my database.
Is there some sort of ML algo I could use to achieve this?
